# Checking a possible logarithm identity: $(\sqrt{2})^{\lg n} \stackrel{?}{=} 2^{\sqrt{2\lg n}}$

Tags: logarithms

I have to check if $(\sqrt{2})^{\lg n} = 2^{\sqrt{2\lg n}}$.
My idea was to take logs: $\lg\ (\sqrt{2})^{\lg n} =\lg(2^{\sqrt{2\lg n}})$.
But how to simplify further? What should I do next? Please, explain in details if possible.

Comment: The left-hand side is $2^{(\log n)/2}$.  The right-hand side is $2^{\sqrt{2\log n}}$.  The only time these are equal is when $(\log n) / 2 = \sqrt{2\log n}$, which is when $\log n = 8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{2}\,^{\log{n}} = (2^{\tfrac{1}{2}})^{\log{n}} = 2^{{\tfrac{1}{2}}\log{n}} = 2\,^{\log{\sqrt{n}}}= (2^{\log{n}})^{\tfrac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{2^{\log{n}}}
\\ =n^{\tfrac{1}{2}log{\,2}} = n^{\log{\sqrt{2}}} =  \sqrt{n}^{\,\log{2}}= \sqrt{n^{\log{2}}}
$$

All of these can be derived from the rules
$$
\log{a^b} = b\log{a}
\\a^{bc} = (a^{b})^c
$$
but they are not equivalent to your RHS expression.

Answer (score 2):

They're not equivalent. For example, take $n = 4$. Then assuming that $\lg x \equiv \log_2 x$, notice that:
$$
(\sqrt 2)^{\lg 4} = (\sqrt 2)^2 = 2 \neq 4
= 2^{2} = 2^{\sqrt{4}} = 2^{\sqrt{2(2)}} = 2^{\sqrt{2 \lg 4}}
$$